# JavaScript causing grunt uglify to fail

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm running [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) as part of my grunt build task. I am currently getting this error:

```
Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: punc ({).
```

The error is caused by this code which is wrapped in a larger function:

```
// Test if browser supports drag and drop
var testSupport = functon() {
    var testElement = document.createElement('div');
    return ('draggable' in testElement) || ('ondragstart' in testElement && 'ondrop' in testElement);
};

//Run test for drag and drop support
if (!testSupport()) {
    return false;
}
```

When I remove this code, uglify completes without error. Why is the code causing uglify to fail?

Comment: Is it because you spelled "function" as "functon"?

Comment: It is. Hanging my head in shame. Thanks!